# Jacobian of Mod function giving zeros as result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Could you please explain the following discrepancy in results ?

```
D[{Mod[Mod[fx, ax], bx], Mod[Mod[fx, ax], bx], 
  Mod[Mod[fx, ax], bx]}, {{ax, bx, cx}}]

out= {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}


D[Mod[Mod[fx, ax], bx], ax]

out = -Floor[fx/ax] + (fx*
    Piecewise[{{0, fx/ax > Floor[fx/ax]}}, Indeterminate])/
  ax - (-Floor[
      fx/ax] + (fx*
       Piecewise[{{0, fx/ax > Floor[fx/ax]}}, Indeterminate])/ax)*
  Piecewise[{{0, Mod[fx, ax]/bx > Floor[Mod[fx, ax]/bx]}}, 
   Indeterminate]
```

Screenshot is given below

[image]

Comment: Copy and paste your code into code blocks rather than posting a picture of the code.

Comment: This does look like a bug. Please report it to Support.

Comment: @J.M. Reported, waiting for a reply.

Comment: Mathematica team is looking into the problem. Looks like a bug.

Comment: The following also seems to work!!  Now I am really curious what is going on!!

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Jacobian.html

  JacobianMatrix[f_List?VectorQ, x_List] :=
    Outer[D, f, x] /; Equal @@ (Dimensions /@ {f, x})

  JacobianDeterminant[f_List?VectorQ, x_List] :=
    Det[JacobianMatrix[f, x]] /;
      Equal @@ (Dimensions /@ {f, x})